# How to find the user moving direction using the bearing value returned by location manager?

Tags: android, locationmanager, direction, compass, bearing

LocationObject.getBearing() returns the horizontal direction of travel of this device[0 to 360 degree].

How to calculate the user moving direction like North, south and all from this bearing value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing%28%29):

> Returns the direction of travel in degrees East of true North. If hasBearing() is false, 0.0 is returned.

- So 0 is north (and the degrees goes clockwise)
- So 90 would be East
- 180 South
- 270 West